# OpenJDK remedy for CVE-2022-21496 yields "unsupported authority" exception thrown

Tags: java, security, ldap, redhat

After a recent RedHat OpenJDK update, an application is logging the following exception on startup while trying to process its configuration properties:

***javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot parse url: ldap://dev_ldap.example.com:389 [Root exception is java.net.MalformedURLException: unsupported authority: dev_ldap.example.com:389]***

What is meant by "unsupported authority"? A related RedHat article suggests only to "avoid special characters", but we don't appear to be using any. (Unless it is the underscore that is considered "special"?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick Internet search result: "The use of underscore characters is a little confusing. Underscore characters are not permitted in domain names in accordance with RFC 1035, which only allows letters, digits and hyphens." [1](https://www.entrust.com/blog/2019/01/removal-of-underscores-from-domain-names/)

Comment: Testing confirmed that the underscore was the problem, so I will accept my own answer when that option is available to me

Comment: have you found any workaround to allow for _ other then using ip?:)

Comment: "As a workaround it's possible to add -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldapURLParsing="legacy" to the JVM arguments to reduce the security level, knowing that the application will be more vulnerable according to the CVE." [Source: RedHat Customer Portal]

Comment: Thanks @wytten, adding that as part of my VM options worked! I'm using open jdk 1.8.0_332-b09

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the environment variable -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldapURLParsing="legacy" as shown here https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8288207